# How to get rid of \ character inside a JSON key (java)

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, escaping

Before you downvote, the problem stands as it is. I am making something for my customer and I must meet his requirements, even if they don't comply with the best practices. I am sure you have been in that situation sometime, and you understand.

I am populating a JSONObject in Eclipse (an android app):

```
jtappedRow="{"label":"red","key":"3"}";
jactionresult.put("value",jtappedRow);
jactionresult.put( bla bla bla..... )
```

but when, print jactionresult on a LOG, like this:

```
Log.e(tag,"TAP THIS TO ENGINE!: "+jactionresult.toString());
```

I get this:

```
TAP THIS TO ENGINE!: {"value":"{\"label\":\"green\",\"key\":\"1\"}","result":"success","action":"displayClickableList"}
```

How to I get rid of those \ characters??? The result I need is exactly this:

```
TAP THIS TO ENGINE!: {"value":"`{"label":"green","key":"1"}","result":"success","action":"displayClickableList"}`
```

Comment: You cannot create `JSONObject` to a `JSONObject`

Comment: I can't see how the very first line of code you've provided would compile at all. It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (Just a plain Java console app...)

Comment: @JonSkeet You may assume that the entire thing compiles runs well (because it does), and that the only problem is that \ character, that is getting in between.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I know it is strange, but it works just as good as doing myJSONobject.toString();

Comment: I can assume you've got something compiling - but it's not the code you've presented, which is really unhelpful. Also note that the "result you need" isn't valid JSON. Do you really not want valid JSON? (And do you really want the backticks in there?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to keep things simple here, putting more things will just add noise into the problem. My debugger shows that value in that variable, in that point, period. Don't worry somebody just earned the green tick a moment ago.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints before you ask your next question. A short but complete program is invaluable for making a good question which will be useful to other readers in the future - pseudo-code isn't. (And it's still not clear why you want invalid JSON...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't want invalid JSON. My customer does. Real life is not always the classroom, sorry

Comment: Well, you've talked about why "you" need - if you're now pushing that broken requirement as "that's just what my customer requires" you should state that in the question. Any time there's something unusual in requirements and you can *anticipate* responses, include that information in the question. (This is far from a matter of "in the classroom" - it's a matter of customers often needing guidance...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the String you posted, you can use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String res = jsonStr.replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will a) give you invalid JSON - as the OP requested, but for reasons that remain unclear; b) it will remove any *other* backslashes introduced, e.g. due to quotes that occur naturally within the value. A solution like this *usually* indicates an inappropriate use of data - leading to things like invalid JSON...

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree. OP didn't post his actual code (and JSON). I hope they're aware of this issue.

Comment: Sorry people, my customer wants it that way. It is a bit frustrating for us developers, but we must bear with these things while we climb to the top. That said, @JonSkeet pointed out the invalid JSON issue correctly.

Comment: If you are aware that it's an unusual (I would say *broken*) requirement, it's always worth explaining that in the question, to avoid any confusion. (I hope you've already pushed back, explaining that what they're getting just isn't JSON...)

Answer (score 0):

String replace or use a framework like jackson or gson for parsing

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the backslash, it means that it is being read as a String. Convert it to JSONObject by using the code below:

```
JSONObject jtappedRow = new JSONObject();
jtappedRow.put("label", "red");
jtappedRow.put("key", "3");
jactionresult.put("value",jtappedRow);
jactionresult.put( bla bla bla..... )
```

or you can do something like this

```
jtappedRow={"label":"red","key":"3"};
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jtappedRow);
jactionresult.put("value", json);
jactionresult.put( bla bla bla..... )
```